# How can I adjust the sizing on the mobile screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Because the quality of my photo is poor on the mobile screen, I cannot fix it to a certain height and the height of the screen is decreasing in proportion, is there any way to fix it? If not, how can I fit my btn-blacks into the photo when mobile?
It would be better if boostrap is not used. If there is no other solution it can be boostrap.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.conta{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  max-width: 1350px;
}

.conta img{
  max-width: 100%
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  width: 420px;
  height: 33%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn-black {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.9rem;
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.btn-black i {
  margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.box-1 .btn-black span {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="tr">

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="berkay.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:768px)" href="tablet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:500px)" href="mobile.css">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="conta">
      <img src="https://www.reidrental.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/general-hire-earthworks-machinery-1350x600.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box box-1">
              <a class="btn-black" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
                <span>GÖRÜNTÜLÜ KONUŞMA</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <a class="btn-black" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
                <span>EMLAKÇILARIMIZ</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <a class="btn-black" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
                <span>EVLERİMİZ</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box box-4">
              <a class="btn-black" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
                <span>ŞUBELERİMİZ</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The container .conta has no given dimensions so it is difficult to give it a background image. On the other hand using a child element img it was reported that object-fit: contain did not show the whole image.

One solution therefore is to put a background image into a pseudo element on container and get rid of the img element entirely.

So, do this:

Remove the image element.

Put this into your CSS:

```
.conta::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(https://www.reidrental.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/general-hire-earthworks-machinery-1350x600.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

This creates a pseudo element (not a real element in the DOM) which covers the whole viewport and uses the image as background - the contain makes sure the whole image can be seen.

Comment: Bro, when you use these features, most of the photo is not visible on the mobile screen. I want the photo to remain the same in all sizes, like the banner on this link (https://www.medicana.com.tr/)

Comment: That's when you use contain not cover - assuming your container is resizing correctly.

Comment: Do you mean the picture of the people? Because that is just set to be as wide as the screen, and at some sizes you don't see all of it.

Comment: OK, the problem stems from .conta not having dimensions. We can get round that and not alter anything in the DOM by getting CSS to add a pseudo element which has the image as background and makes sure all of it can be seen. Answer updated and also tested on the snippet and it worked.

Comment: It worked for the background, thank you, but they do not move with the btn-blacks. When the screen size changes, they go out of the picture. I will try to solve it. If I can't, can you help me again? And what was the reason for giving "before"?

Comment: Hi, are you saying that the buttons go out of the picture, but that the picture still can be seen? This sounds like a slightly different question so we may have to move to chat shortly but I’m willing to still try to help if I can.

Comment: The pseudo element could have been before or after, as it’s positioned absolutely it doesn’t matter. Before seemed more natural as it gets painted on the screen then other stuff in the container gets displayed.